# Need to send request to backend api (LARAVEL) on specific route VUE

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue world. My Application was built on Laravel only. But I am upgrading it to make it SPA as Vue is my front end and Laravel is only API (both separate).
In Laravel, when we load any view we can send data to view as;

```
$roles = Role::whereNotIn('id', [1])->get();
return view('auth.register', compact('roles'));
```

But I don't know how to load this data in Vue on a specific route.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: convert data to json format and return that data in response

Comment: I am asking how to get it in Vue?
What should I do?
Use a method? computed property? I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can return json response like this.

```
$roles = Role::whereNotIn('id', [1])->get();
return response()->json(['roles' => $roles]);
```

In after getting response, you can use response.roles to get all roles in vue js.

Comment: I know it, I am asking about how to get it in vue js? Use a method? computed property? I am totally new

Comment: @ok You need api call from vue js. I am not familiar with vue js. In react js we can use axios, there would be something like that.

Comment: Ok Thank you! :)